# Require returns an array instead of a boolean

Tags: ruby, require

According to the documentation for [Kernel#require](http://rdoc.info/stdlib/core/1.8.7/Kernel#require-instance_method) the method returns a boolean value. I noticed in a IRB session however that for some files `require` returns an array.

```
ruby-1.8.7-p330 :001 > require 'net/http'
=> true 
ruby-1.8.7-p330 :002 > require 'date'
=> true 
ruby-1.8.7-p330 :003 > require 'lib/data_provider'
=> ["DataProviders"]
```

The returned array contains the name of a module defined in data_provider.rb:

```
module DataProviders
  module Cached
    class Foo
    # ...
    end
  end

  class Foo
  # ...
  end
end
```

Is this a sign of me doing something wrong or some undocumented behavior of `require`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it neither on 1.8.7 nor on 1.9.2. Furthermore, I took a look at the source (eval.c:7405) and the function doesn't seem to be able to return anything except true/false.

Comment: Ok, I think I've got it now. Turned out I had `require 'rubygems'` and `require 'active_support'` earlier in that IRB session. And it looks like Rails' ActiveSupport is causing the difference in behavior. There is a `require` method in [ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Loadable](http://rdoc.info/docs/rails/2.3.8/ActiveSupport/Dependencies/Loadable#require-instance_method).

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce it too. But it's possible that some gem overrides `Kernel#require`:

```
module Kernel
  alias_method :old_require, :require
  def require(str)
    old_modules = []
    ObjectSpace.each_object(Module) {|m| old_modules << m }

    old_require(str)

    new_modules = []
    ObjectSpace.each_object(Module) {|m| new_modules << m unless old_modules.include?(m) }
    new_modules
  end
end
```

and when you try to require

```
module DataProviders
  module Cached
    class Foo
    end
  end
  class Foo
  end
end
```

you will get

```
irb(main):012:0> require 'data_provider'
=> [DataProviders::Cached::Foo, DataProviders::Foo, DataProviders::Cached, DataProviders]
```

Comment: Yes, you're right - see my comment on the question. The gem that must have overriden `require` is Rails's ActiveSupport.

Comment: +1 yes Activesupport does a lot of evil things overriding core methods.  Hopefully Ruby 2 will address this with "refinements" http://yehudakatz.com/2010/11/30/ruby-2-0-refinements-in-practice/